# Proving $\cot { A+\cot { B+\cot { C=\frac { { a }^{ 2 }+{ b }^{ 2 }+{ c }^{ 2 } }{ 4K } } } } $

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, triangles

> For any acute $\triangle ABC$, prove that $\cot { A+\cot { B+\cot { C=\frac { { a }^{ 2 }+{ b }^{ 2 }+{ c }^{ 2 } }{ 4K }  }  }  } $, where $K$ is the area of $\triangle ABC$.

Unfortunately I'm not able to progress in this problem. Any kind help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like it might have to do something with Heron's formula  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a straightforward solution

$\cot A+\cot B+\cot C = \frac{\cos A}{\sin A}+\frac{\cos B}{\sin B}+\frac{\cos C}{\sin C}=\frac{(b^2+c^2-a^2)}{2bc\frac{a}{2R}}+\frac{(a^2+c^2-b^2)}{2ac\frac{b}{2R}}+\frac{(a^2+b^2-c^2)}{2ab\frac{c}{2R}}$.

Now use $\frac{abc}{4R}=K$

Comment: Does the first line use something called the cosine rule?

Comment: Yes, I used $\ cos A =\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$ (cosine rule) and analogously for CosB, etc.

Comment: Ahh.. I am ashamed. I should have learnt that before posting this problem :(

Comment: I also used $\frac{a}{\sin A}=2R$ which is the sine rule.

Comment: What does R represent? The only sine rule I've ever learned is $\dfrac {\sin  A}{a} = \dfrac {\sin  B}{b} = \dfrac {\sin  C}{c}$

Comment: Circumradius of the triangle.

Comment: @Ovi , R is the circumradius of the triangle. The extended form of the sine rule is $\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B}=\frac{c}{\sin C}=2R$. :)

Comment: Oh okay thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$\cot A=\dfrac{\cos A}{\sin A}=\dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2abc}$$

Now $\triangle =\dfrac{abc}{4R}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $4K = 4\cdot \dfrac{abc}{4R}= \dfrac{abc}{R}= 2bc\sin A\Rightarrow 4K\cot A = 2bc\cos A = b^2+c^2 - a^2$